# SQL Method to retrieve a value

Tags: sql, oracle, methods, return-value, user-defined-types

In SQL, how can I create a simple method to retrieve a value from an object?

Here is the code:

```
create type CurrentUser_objtyp as Object (
CurrUserName varchar2(20),
CurrUserPassword varchar2(20),
CurrUserType varchar2(15)
)
/
```

How can I retrieve the value of CurrUserName from a method?

Answer (score 1):

As Oracle SQL types only allow public attributes there is no point in creating getter and setter methods for them.

But the general principle is to create member methods:

```
create type CurrentUser_objtyp as Object (
CurrUserName varchar2(20),
CurrUserPassword varchar2(20),
CurrUserType varchar2(15),
member function getname return varchar2
)
/
```

You need to write a body for the implementation, which is basically PL/SQL:

```
create type body CurrentUser_objtyp as 

    member function getname return varchar2
    is
    begin
         return self.CurrUserName;
    end;
end;
/
```

---

> "How do I call the member function in your above code?"

To call a member function (or procedure) we first have to instantiate the object.  There are various different ways of using objects, but again here is the simplest:

```
declare
    currUser CurrentUser_objtyp := new CurrentUser_objtyp('MR KNOX', 'PASSWORD1', 'MANAGER');
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('user name is '||currUser.getname);
end;
/
```

Oracle have devoted an entire manual to their Object-Relational constructs.  You should read it to [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/toc.htm).

Comment: Thanks. How do I call the member function in your above code?